# jain-sip /jsip getListeningPoint method was removed from RequestEvent and ResponseEvent

Tags: jain-sip

I have a JAIN-SIP project with one `SipStack`, multiple `SipProviders` each with one `ListeningPoint`. In earlier versions of the sip stack, when a request/response come in, I could just call: `requestEvent.getListeningPoint().getIPAddress()`, but the `getListeningPoint()` function was removed. How am I supposed to find out, to which ip address and port the request come in?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the event source i.e. Event.getSource() of the event delivered to your listener method.